# Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apac he.maven.plugins

Tags: maven

I am getting the below error while trying to perform mvn clean:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its 
dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5:
```

Do you have any idea of how to solve it?

**POM file:**

-http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">

4.0.0

com.jenkov

hello-world

1.0.0

Comment: Can you please provide your `pom.xml` or the relevant parts if it is very large? Otherwise it's unlikely that anyone could come up with a relevant answer to your question. Thanks!

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>

-<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.jenkov</groupId>

<artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>

<version>1.0.0</version>

</project>

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit: please add the information by editing the original question instead of posting it as a comment, especially when it's code. As you can see, code in comments is hard to read if it's more than a short statement.

Comment: That looks like a network issue firewall/proxy etc. which means Maven can't correctly download all needed plugins/artifacts...